# How to put the xml header, with "<?xml" in php

Tags: php, simplexml

First of all: I'm new with the `SimpleXMLElement` object, so maybe i'm doing something wrong.

I have to load this string:

```
$xmlTipologie=simplexml_load_string(html_entity_decode("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><content>".$temp_dom->saveHTML()."</content>", null, "UTF-8"));
```

But this is the error I get:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in ....content/plugins/soap-SGS/soap-SGS.php on line 115
```

Without adding the header of the xml I get this error.
Maybe there is another way to add the header of a xml in a php string, and if there is I'd be happy that you wrote below, but now I'm curious of another thing:

How can i put  this char -> `<?` in a php string? "Obvious when the short tag mode is set on the php.ini?)

Edit, i use htmlspecialchars in this way:

```
    $xmlTipologie=simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>".htmlspecialchars("<content><![CDATA[".$temp_dom->saveHTML()."]]></content>",ENT_QUOTES));
```

And this is the new error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in
>   /Users/paolo.cargnin/Sites/happycamp/wp-content/plugins/soap-SGS/soap-SGS.php
>   on line 116

Mh... I can't debug it and this hurt me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Won't `html_entity_decode()` corrupt the XML code?

Comment: what up with `**` at the beginning of the xml content

Comment: Whatever, you can't start/end PHP mode from within strings, so PHP short open tag settings should be irrelevant here.

Comment: @DevZer0 I've just try to make it bold with the editor of stack overrflow... I'm going to edit it, thanks

Comment: why do you have `html_entity_decode`? whats encoded? did you mean to use htmlspecialchars to put the html as a single elements in the <content> tag more like using CDATA

Comment: Why not use heredoc syntax, or just single quote string delimiters? Works for me

Comment: You appear to be bundling one XML document inside another, and then immediately parsing the second XML document, which will give you back the (encoded) inner XML. Can you clarify what it is you are actually trying to achieve - this looks like an attempted solution rather than the original problem. (This is sometimes called [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: Yeah... I got it... The problem is somewhere else ;) I'll continue my debugging and try to make a better question next time. Thank you.

Comment: If this question is unlikely to be helpful in future, I believe you as the author can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

PHP

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<content>
Call function here
</content>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
$xmlTipologie=simplexml_load_string(html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><content>".$temp_dom->saveHTML()."</content>"), null, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: if `htmlspecialchars` will be used it should be used in the `<content>` tag contents not the full xml document